# AbortSystemShutdown on Windows 7 not working

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shutdown, system-administration

I want to prevent shutdown on Windows 7. I acquire `se_shutdown_privilege` successfully, but `AbortSystemShutdown` is always failing. I tried `AbortSystemShutdown(NULL)`, `AbortSystemShutdown("127.0.0.1")`, and `AbortSystemShutdown(PcName)`.

So far no success.

Comment: Do you check what GetLastError() returns when AbortSystemShutdown() returns 0?

Comment: I get 0x0000045C i think its "Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.", damn i was pretty sure that i got this working before on win 7....

Comment: Maybe i can get it working with some registry keys tweaking ?

Comment: Possibly related: [Now that Windows makes it harder for your program to block shutdown, how do you block shutdown?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/06/14/10319617.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, `AbortSystemShutDown` aborts a shutdown invoked by [InitiateSystemShutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376873%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (and the [Ex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) version of that function) rather than, say, `ExitWindows`.

> The InitiateSystemShutdown and InitiateSystemShutdownEx functions
>   display a dialog box that notifies the user that the system is
>   shutting down. During the shutdown time-out period, the
>   AbortSystemShutdown function can prevent the system from shutting
>   down.

Comment: @VisaToHell: are you sure?  It shouldn't.  In what circumstances are you calling AbortSystemShutdown, i.e., why is the system shutting down?

Comment: @VisaToHell The MSDN documentation says that AbortSystemShutdown aborts what InitiateSystemShutdown initiates. Specifically, it'll abort during the timeout interval set by the initiate function. If you happen to discover on Monday that it works in other undocumented circumstances, that does not mean it will do the same thing on Tuesday. The API documentation is the contract.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me on Windows 7 x64.  Since you didn't post any code I have no idea what you're doing differently.  The `SetPrivilege` function was copied from this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I start the shutdown by typing this in a command prompt: 'shutdown /s /t 500000' and running the program cancels it.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

BOOL SetPrivilege(HANDLE hToken, LPCTSTR lpszPrivilege, BOOL bEnablePrivilege) 
{
    TOKEN_PRIVILEGES tp;
    LUID luid;

    if ( !LookupPrivilegeValue(NULL, lpszPrivilege, &luid ) )
    {
        printf("LookupPrivilegeValue error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
        return FALSE; 
    }

    tp.PrivilegeCount = 1;
    tp.Privileges[0].Luid = luid;
    tp.Privileges[0].Attributes = bEnablePrivilege ? SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED : 0;

    if ( !AdjustTokenPrivileges(hToken, FALSE, &tp, sizeof(TOKEN_PRIVILEGES), (PTOKEN_PRIVILEGES) NULL, (PDWORD) NULL) )
    { 
        printf("AdjustTokenPrivileges error: %u\n", GetLastError() ); 
        return FALSE; 
    } 

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ALL_ASSIGNED)
    {
        printf("The token does not have the specified privilege. \n");
        return FALSE;
    } 
    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hToken;
    OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES, &hToken);
    if(!SetPrivilege(hToken, SE_SHUTDOWN_NAME, TRUE))
    {
        printf("Could not adjust privileges\n");
    }
    if(!AbortSystemShutdown(NULL))
    {
        printf("AbortSystemShutdown failed (%08x)", GetLastError());
    }
    CloseHandle(hToken);
    return 0;
}
```